# Decompile and deobfuscate python files

Tags: python, base64, obfuscation, deobfuscation

One of our employees, has created a python application which he has obfescated and then base64 encoded. 
Currently, the employee is on suspension following other actions and won't decompile or provide the code base. HR are sorting.

I need to de-obfuscate the file, so I can read what he has created and present to HR. Can anyone help?

It's obfuscated using https://github.com/lhr0909/PythonObfuscator (I found his command history) and then base64 encoded.

Comment: Base 64 decoding is trivial, deobfuscating may not be (putting e.g. sensible variable names back can't be automated). Just go back to an earlier revision (and if you weren't using source control...) If there are *"other actions"*, why does it even matter?

Comment: `python -m trace --trace script.py` should give you all the calls the scripts execute. What you're doing is forensic evidence I guess and it's a dirty job. There are some tools to de-obfuscate but they are rarely complete.

Comment: That why *some* people are using version control systems...

Comment: @jonrsharpe this staff member unfortunately didn't update the git repo with a revisioned version without obfuscation. I'm just the middle man here, doing what I'm instructed to do by our HR team..

Comment: @Carl given the info below, it seems you have the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217926/how-to-decode-a-python-string; it's trivial to put back together.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe certainly looks familiar.. I certianly hope this member of staff is running an XBMC plugin from our server.. Appreciate the link, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 9):

It's pretty easy to unobfuscate that particular obfuscator because it doesn't actually change any of the identifiers.
Take a simple piece of code:

```
from random import randrange
print([[randrange(n) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)])
```

Which generates:

```
exec("import re;import base64");exec((lambda p,y:(lambda o,b,f:re.sub(o,b,f))(r"([0-9a-f]+)",lambda m:p(m,y),base64.b64decode("NyA0IDMgMAo1KFtbMCg4KSAyIDkgNiAxKDgpXSAyIDkgNiAxKDgpXSk=")))(lambda a,b:b[int("0x"+a.group(1),16)],"randrange|range|for|import|random|print|in|from|n|_".split("|")))
```

Replacing the second `exec` with `print`:

```
exec("import re;import base64");print((lambda p,y:(lambda o,b,f:re.sub(o,b,f))(r"([0-9a-f]+)",lambda m:p(m,y),base64.b64decode("NyA0IDMgMAo1KFtbMCg4KSAyIDkgNiAxKDgpXSAyIDkgNiAxKDgpXSk=")))(lambda a,b:b[int("0x"+a.group(1),16)],"randrange|range|for|import|random|print|in|from|n|_".split("|")))
                                ^^^^^
```

Running this now reveals:

```
from random import randrange
print([[randrange(n) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)])
```

Comment: Hi @Achampion, thank you for your response. I'll run that through now.. I can decode the base64, but then the code is obfuscated, would such decode that also?

Comment: @Carl see the question I linked above; it's simply a find and replace for hex indices

Comment: @Carl the obfuscator encodes in base64, if that is the only base64 you are talking about then yes it decodes it.

Comment: @jonsharpe impressive piece of reverse engineering but a bit overkill when a simple `print` replacement extracts all the text.

Comment: Hi @AChampion thank you for your explanation, I appreciate it.. So I have decoded the file, and now the text is a series of

0o0=iiIIIiiiii

I saw that he has used https://github.com/astrand/pyobfuscate to obfuscate it

Comment: @AChampion that was more for the purposes of explanation than practical use! As you say, just printing instead of executing shows you what it is.

Comment: @Carl sorry identifier renaming, docstring removal etc. is not reversible. You can pass it through a python indenter, which will reformat it - but other than that - you will have to work out what it does without the help of meaningful identifiers